# Geodesics of lie groups with left invariant metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I am dealing with matrix lie groups, Like GL(n) or subgroups of GL(n).
Does geodesics of these matrix lie groups with left invariant metrics are related to one parameter subgroups?
Can someone offer some references or examples for me for further study?

Comment: The answer is yes, these are related and a covered in most books on Lie groups. To begin with, Bump's book on Lie groups has a chapter titled Geodesics and maximal tori which discusses this in the compact setting. In the non-compact setting, one needs to also consider unipotent and parabolic directions, which gets more involved.